# Separate points inside set

Tags: algorithms, optimization, computational-geometry

I have a set of points corresponding to pictures on map. Because location precision is not very important, I want to separate the points inside the set to maximize the summed up distance between the points. There would be a maximum distance that points could be moved.

Any idea what kind of algorithm should I use?

Comment: So you want to separate points that are close to each other so that they're easier to distinguish/click?

Comment: You want to maximize the sum of all distances between any two points, i.e. n(n-1)/2 distances?

Comment: It is not clear to me that it will give you the best results, assuming I understand your purpose. If 2 points are already far apart, is there any point in increasing that distance, possibly at the expense of points that are close to each other.

Comment: Yes, I want to maximize the sum of all distance between any two points. To avoid separating even more two distant points one could set a minimum threshold. So, don't move points witch are more than X separated.